# If URL is entered data is not fetched from Database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a basic app structure where I call data (the iPhones in the database) from the AppComponent itself.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.iphoneservice.fetchIphones();
  }
```

The fetchIphones method is in my iPhoneService file where I have 3 functions.

```
iPhoneList:iPhone[]=[]
fetchIphones(){
    this.http
      .get('https://angular-project-62585-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/iphone.json')
      .pipe(
        map(responseData =>{
        const postArray =[];
        for(const key in responseData){
          if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            postArray.push({...responseData[key],id:key});
          }
        }
        return postArray 
      })
      )
      .subscribe(post =>{
        this.generateIphoneList(post)
      })
  }



  // Generating the IphoneList from the fetched Data
  generateIphoneList(post){
    this.iPhoneList=[];
    for (let iphones of post){
      let iphone = new iPhone()
      for (let property in iphones){
          iphone[property]=iphones[property];
        }
      this.iPhoneList.push(iphones);
    }
  }
    

  // Returning the IphoneList to desired components
  getiPhone(){
    return this.iPhoneList;
  }
```

The First two functions create the iPhoneList array and after that from my iPhoneFront-Component I  retrive the data from the with the getiPhone function.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.iPhoneList=this.iphoneservice.getiPhone();
  }
```

My Problem is that when I go to the page via the Navbar the data is fetched and visible, but if I go to the webpage manually via the URL the data is not fetched. My HTML for the navbar and the AppModule are below.

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/iphone" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">iPhone</a>
</li>




const appRoutes : Routes =[
  {path:'iphone',
  children:[
    {path:'',component:IphonefrontComponent},
    {path:':id',component:IphonedetailComponent},
  ]
},
  {path:'iphone-managing',
  canActivate:[AuthenticationGuard],
  children:[
    {path:'',component:IphonebackComponent},
    {path:'create',component:IphonecreateComponent},
    {path:':id',component:IphoneeditComponent},
  ]},
  {path:'cart',component:CartComponent},
  {path:'authentication',component:AuthenticationComponent},
]
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I think its just a simple timing issue. Instead of holding the list as a normal list use a behavior subject, that you can subscribe to, so when the data is available it can show it in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen answer I declared Behavior Subject and changed my Service accordingly.

```
iPhoneList:iPhone[]=[];
iPhoneListSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.iPhoneList);


generateIphoneList(post){
    this.iPhoneList=[];
    for (let iphones of post){
      let iphone = new iPhone()
      for (let property in iphones){
          iphone[property]=iphones[property];
        }
      this.iPhoneList.push(iphones);
      this.iPhoneListSubject.next(this.iPhoneList)
    }
  }


getiPhone(){
    return this.iPhoneListSubject;
  }
```

And after the getiPhone method is called I subsribed to the Behavior Subject.

```
iPhoneList:iPhone[]=[]

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.iphoneservice.getiPhone().subscribe(
        list=>{
          this.iPhoneList=list
        }
      );
  }
```